# Why can't I load any js after my blazor.server.js?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

So I noticed that in my _Host.cshtml file I have this script before the `</body>` tag

```
 <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

And I also have some scripts that are suppose to load after that which are these

```
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/popper/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/feather/feather.min.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/typeahead/typeahead.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/typeahead/typeahead-active.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/pace/pace.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/highlight/highlight.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Articles Script -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/dataTable/datatables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/plugins/summernote/summernote.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
    <!-- Required Script -->
    <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/avesta.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/avesta-customizer.js"></script>

</body>
```

However, if I have the blazor.js script at the top, my menu won't act normal, it will stop working and look like this.
I'm actually clicking a lot and it's not animating as you can see.

[image]

However if I put the blazor.server.js script at the bottom to load last, it works just fine and looks like this

[image]

But then if I load it last, I get this in my console

[image]

which results in my not being able to do this

```
<input @bind="@CurrentValue" @oninput="@((e) => { CurrentValue=(string)e.Value;})" @onkeypress="KeyPress" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
```

It just doesn't hit the function at all, nothing happens, it doesnt register it.

Comment: Some request is causing the websocket to get closed. Check the network tab for the last websocket request that is executed correctly, that may give you a clue about what's happening

Comment: @Gusman everything in the network tab returns `200` except the last one which returns 101 https://i.imgur.com/90Jk9Q3.png

Comment: which browser do you use? maybe it doesn't supports ws request debugging, in Firefox per example you must enable it explicitly

Comment: @Gusman Seems to show the exact same on Chrome

Comment: It's strange because it tells you that it has connected to the websocket but it doesn't appears in the network tab... I'm out of ideas, if I think anithing else will get back, sorry.

Comment: @Gusman I appreciate the effort!

Comment: When you click on your items and it's not working, how are the represented in the DOM? Are they hidden but still present, or are they totally removed and reinserted by the JS scripts and / or Blazor calls? By default, Blazor rendered items are not present if they aren't shown, meaning heavy use of JS can have strange effects on Blazor Server as it might be trying to operate on objects that just aren't there or maybe aren't rendered yet, and then manipulations on things that are there can confuse the tracking for the virtual DOM used to calculate the diffs. Just a thought.

Comment: @RileyVarga, do u found any solution for ur issue? Im facing same issue. My js not rendering properly .. even i tried placing the server.js at the last . but no use.

Comment: @RileyVarga were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? In my case the src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script> script blocks all other JS files whether it's placed on top or bottom. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 4):

Using the Net5, You can now reference your scripts on the main layout by overriding the `OnAfterRenderAsync`. Here is an example

You will first inherit IJSRuntime

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
```

Then here is the Code:

```
@code {        
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if(firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer on the internet.. saved me from ditching Blazor or rewriting the UI scripts in Blazor

Comment: Can you guys if possible share screen shot or show how you add JavaScript Libraries Reference and Where (e.g. MainLayout.razor or _Host.cshtml)

Answer (score 1):

Can you guys if possible share screen shot or show how you added JavaScript Libraries Reference in project to make it work and Where (e.g. **MainLayout.razor** or **_Host.cshtml**) also where you guys added **blazor.server.js**

I tried both ways adding JavaScript references in _Host.cshtml file before  tag like following. But it didn't worked.

```html
<script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/custom/prismjs/prismjs.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/scripts.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/custom/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/custom/widgets.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/pages/custom/wizard/wizard-5.js"></script>
```

Then I added as you suggested in last comments under MainLayout.razor page even that didn't worked. For MainLayout please see following (In this case If I inspect page element it is not showing any JavaScript References in Page Tags.

```html
@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "_framework/blazor.server.js");
            await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.js");
            await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/plugins/custom/prismjs/prismjs.bundle.js");
            await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/js/scripts.bundle.js");
            await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/plugins/custom/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.bundle.js");
            await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/js/pages/widgets.js");
            await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/js/pages/custom/wizard/wizard-5.js");
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** I also tried with ~/  or  /  or ../ just before library path but didn't worked for me.

Comment: If you don't let blazor.server.js start in page you won't have OnAfterRenderAsync fired.
blazor.server.js runs the events in page.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a complete solution (at least for me yet) as it's causing all sorts of racing conditions - but seems like I'm on the correct path of solving this - hopefully some time within the next decade.

Seems like one of the nicer ways of doing this is disabling the `autostart` on `blazor.server|webassembly.js` link, and then adding the JS file imports by adding them as elements.

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false"></script>
```

After this, create a  below your blazor import, and import your elements to the page. You will see them being added to the page after Blazor is loaded. Excuse the dirty code, it's WIP and I'm still experimenting.

```
<script>
    Blazor.start().then(function () {

        var customScript = document.createElement('script');
        customScript.setAttribute('src', 'assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.js');
        document.body.appendChild(customScript);
        
        var anotherScript = document.createElement('script');
        anotherScript.setAttribute('src', 'assets/js/scripts.bundle.js');
        document.body.appendChild(anotherScript);
    });
</script>
```

If you don't add the `autostart="false"` attribute, you'll see an error message in console, saying that the Blazor has already started.

My understanding is that `await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<Iblah>("import", "blah.js");` is meant for Razor components, but correct me if I'm wrong. If anyone wonders, I'm using Metronic, not that it matters.

Comment: @Riley if you've found a solution for this, I'd really appreciate if you could share. Ideally before I lose my remaining hair.

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using `.net 7`, you can reference the `JS` inside the `OnAfterRenderAsync` under the code section of the blazor component you want to use use/call the JS.

Eg: Assuming you want to call the `script.js` JS under the index component, then you need to add the following code to the `@code` section of the index component;

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        var jsModule = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./assets/js/script.js");
        
    }
}
```

Where `assets/js/script.js` is the file location inside the `wwwroot` folder.