# Why is my Blazor @onclick MouseEventArg not working?

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-5

I have a simple .RAZOR component in my Blazor (.NET 5) project that looks like this:

```
<div>
    <input id="searchInput" type="text" name="queryString" @bind="queryString" />
    <button type="button" @onclick="PerformSearch">Search</button>
</div>

@code {
    public String queryString;

    public void PerformSearch()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Why aren't you working? - " + queryString);
    }
}
```

However, when I click the button, the `PerformSearch` does not get called at all. There are no errors (compile time or run time) in my code. When I put a breakpoint at the `Console.Writeline()` line, it never gets there at all, and there is nothing in the log that tells me why this is (or isn't) happening.

Comment: Are you 100% positive you are looking at the page you think you are?  (the code seems fine)

Comment: I am, and it's weird. I created a new project with **just** this one component in it and it works just fine. There is, apparently, something in my larger, main project that is doing this to me, but I don't know what, and it's killing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found out what the issue was. I had removed this line:

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

from the `_Host.cshtml` page. When I put it back at the end of the line:

```
        <script src="~/js/jquery/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/JavaScript.js"></script>
        <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Everything started working again.

The fact that this is what broke my page is infuriating, as one of Microsoft's big selling points for Blazor is that it doesn't need JavaScript.

Guess not.

---

**EDIT:** To tag onto this answer of mine, the `blazor.server.js` will prevent any of your other JavaScripts from working, no matter if it is listed first or last in the lineup. In order to get your JavaScript to work, or Blazor, jQuery, etc., you will need to follow **[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66382964/319020)** StackOverflow answer.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think that "Blazor doesn't need JavaScript" is a big misconception, and is certainly not in Microsoft's messaging anywhere. The truth is, there are a lot of things that Blazor accomplishes only via JavaScript, because JavaScript is the only way a browser exposes that functionality.  That "blazor.server.js" file is and always has been a critical piece of the framework.

Comment: Several Blazor libraries have been written specifically to wrap up the necessary JavaScript interop (like to access localStorage) so that other developers can write C# and not be bothered writing the small bit of JavaScript you need. But it's still JavaScript under the hood.

Comment: And it's certainly possible to write a completely functional Blazor app without *writing* a single line of JavaScript, even though lots of JavaScript is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: So don't get discouraged, but also don't think that it's *either* JavaScript *or* C# in a Blazor app. The engine that runs things is a combination of both.

Comment: A big part (arguably the main part) of Blazor is writing UI, which manipulates the DOM.  This is not possible in WebAssembly, so naturally that requires JS.